# How can I reset the motion effect of a UIView correctly?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, motion

I have extended the UIView class in order to implement my own quick method for adding a motion effect in a UIView:

```
#import "UIView+Extensions.h"

@implementation UIView (Extensions)

// ...

- (void)setMotion:(CGPoint)motion
{
    // Remove all motion effects.
    if (self.motionEffects.count > 0) {

        [self removeMotionEffect:[self.motionEffects objectAtIndex:0]];
        [self removeMotionEffect:[self.motionEffects objectAtIndex:1]];
    }

    // Add motion effects.
    UIInterpolatingMotionEffect *horizontalMotionEffect = [[UIInterpolatingMotionEffect alloc] initWithKeyPath:@"center.x" type:UIInterpolatingMotionEffectTypeTiltAlongHorizontalAxis];
    UIInterpolatingMotionEffect *verticalMotionEffect = [[UIInterpolatingMotionEffect alloc] initWithKeyPath:@"center.y" type:UIInterpolatingMotionEffectTypeTiltAlongVerticalAxis];

    [self addMotionEffect:horizontalMotionEffect];
    [self addMotionEffect:verticalMotionEffect];

    // Set motion effect values.
    horizontalMotionEffect.minimumRelativeValue = @(-motion.x);
    horizontalMotionEffect.maximumRelativeValue = @(motion.x);

    verticalMotionEffect.minimumRelativeValue = @(-motion.y);
    verticalMotionEffect.maximumRelativeValue = @(motion.y);
}
```

I'm getting a counter-intuitive error.

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 ..
>   0]'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x28d3749f 0x3652ec8b 0x28c4bc35 0x7ab1f 0x79e95 0x7d983 0x7a39f 0x6969f 0x7ddf3 0x2c1f9d0f 0x2c1f9a7d
>   0x2c1ff953 0x2c1fd3bd 0x2c26760d 0x2c45951b 0x2c45b98b 0x2c466209
>   0x2c45a217 0x2f4c80d1 0x28cfdd7d 0x28cfd041 0x28cfbb7b 0x28c493c1
>   0x28c491d3 0x2c25e1bf 0x2c258fa1 0x7f425 0x36aaeaaf) libc++abi.dylib:
>   terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Which means that somehow this line of code:

```
[self removeMotionEffect:[self.motionEffects objectAtIndex:0]];
```

Removes both effects instead of just the first one.

How is that even possible?

And this is not the worst part....

As you might suggest, changing the code to this:

```
// Remove all motion effects.
if (self.motionEffects.count > 0) {

    [self removeMotionEffect:[self.motionEffects objectAtIndex:0]]; // Should remove the first, or both but removes the second one.
}
```

Should fix the problem since the line of code above will remove both.
IT DOES NOT. **It actually removes the vertical effect, the second one!**
So, each time you reset the motion the horizontal axis adds-up and goes
faster and faster.

This is beyond reasoning.

Answer (score 3):

After the first

```
[self removeMotionEffect:[self.motionEffects objectAtIndex:0]];
```

self.motionEffects will contain only 1 object, so you can't use objectAtIndex:1 because you'll get the out of bounds exception...

Use

```
[self.motionEffects firstObject]
```

or some loops to do it...

Answer (score 1):

Actually when the object at index zero is removed, the index of other items in the array is changed. For example, index of item at index 1 will be changed to 0 after removing the object at index 0. You can make this code work just by swapping the two lines in the condition **if (self.motionEffects.count > 0)**

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4

```
extension UIView {
    func stopParallax() {
        for motion in motionEffects {
            removeMotionEffect(motion)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't just post the code, try to explain why your particular approach fixes the OP's issue.